# DIV rotate in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I am currently trying to rotate this div toward the mouse pointer, and it hasnt worked. I even tried going to a chat room about it. Currently, It sorta rotates toward the mouse...here is my code so far:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
    x = Number(event.pageX);
    y = Number(event.pageY);
}, false);

setInterval(function(){
    var boxX = document.getElementById('temp').style.left;
    boxX = Number(boxX.substring(0, boxX.length - 1));
    var boxX = screen.width * ((boxX)/100);
    var boxY = document.getElementById('temp').style.top;
    boxY = Number(boxY.substring(0, boxY.length - 1));
    var boxY = screen.width * ((boxY)/100);
    var slope = [Math.round(x - boxX),Math.round(y - boxY)]; 
    //x,y
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan(slope[1]/slope[0]) *100) ;
    document.getElementById('temp').style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0deg)";
    document.getElementById('temp').style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%) rotate("+angle+"deg)";
}, 500);
```